# npm run build:prod crashing in Ubuntu 16.04 but not Windows 10

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm, npm-run

I'm trying to run "npm run build:prod", but I'm getting errors on Ubuntu 16.04 which I don't see in Windows 10. I have recent versions of npm and node. I can't tell if this is a problem with npm or angular.

I checked the debug log and it says it's failing at the angular 2 node js script... but doesn't really point me to any specific modules that are having any problems.

npm-v: 5.3.0
node-v: 8.6.0

the package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'",
    "ngc": "ngc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "6.0.45",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.79.0",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.21",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
  }
}
```

debug log

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~prebuild: angular2-nodejs@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: angular2-nodejs@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/tony/web/sa_website/node_modules/.bin:/home/tony/bin:/home/tony/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: CWD: /home/tony/web/sa_website
10 silly lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch' ]
11 silly lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle angular2-nodejs@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: angular2-nodejs@0.0.0 build: `del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid angular2-nodejs@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/tony/web/sa_website
16 verbose Linux 4.8.0-58-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.6.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error angular2-nodejs@0.0.0 build: `del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the angular2-nodejs@0.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the debug log file. I think that you will find a missing module (or incompatible module).

Comment: I added the debug log, but don't really see any specific module problems, or maybe I'm reading it wrong. Seems like an angular problem?

Comment: The build is failing with this command: del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch. I don't see an obvious error here. Double check your file permissions. Hopefully this will help you get closer.

Comment: Try this. delete the node_modules directory and then re-download the modules. Make sure that the delete really completes. Another thing, try to manually delete public/js/app and make sure that this completes. Lastly double check your package.json for something Windows specific that does not work or is incorrect on your Ubuntu system. As a last resort try recreating package.json so that it is specific to your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: If I remember correctly the package del-cli is for Windows builds. Try replacing this with the del module.

Comment: Thank you! The del-cli was the problem. I remember reading that but I spaced it switching to Linux